# Are there any tests for one's belief or philosophy?

Tags: reference-request, measurement, motivation, test, statistics

I know of the varying types of personality tests and I find them interesting (specifically HEXACO due to it having multiple facets to expand its 6 main factors and I believe it is open-source or free to use to some extent). I was wondering if there exists any psychological tests that determine one's beliefs or philosophy?

I know of the Dark Triad, but that's still more personality than belief. The difference I am trying to define is that personality tests seem to me to state what a person does or how they act, but not necessarily attempt to define their reasoning or motives. I believe a psychological belief test could be interesting, and/or (if different) a test of how one's personal philosophy is correlated to academic philosophies, meaning the well-established and studied philosophies.

Any resources and thoughts are welcomed here.

---

Psychological profiling may accomplish to some extent what I am looking for, but I am uncertain. These may help reveal one's motivations to some degree, which is still something useful.

Comment: Here are a few, prijatelju. http://www.philosophyexperiments.com/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the website. Admittedly, I have seen it before. Although itself is not of much use as an answer to my question, given its promotion of revaluation (& other biases) rather than one time evaluation, the website does provide references to the research backing their tests. These will help lead me to find articles that have cited these papers and improved them. I find formal research on these tests more valuable than most generic website quizzes. I am still looking for formal psychological and cognitive science tests and research to determine ones reasoning/motives.

Answer (score 1):

The confidence in one's own ability to achieve intended results is assessed by tests on **self-efficacy**

Self-efficacy or personal efficacy is a dimension developed by Bandura (1997) in his *social cognitive theory*.

He also developed some tests which assess the sefl-efficacy in many situations:

- Academic self-efficacy
- Self-efficacy to regulate eating habits
- Driving self-efficacy
- Problem solving self- efficacy
- Teacher self-efficacy

And a great deal more scales. In fact  *"the efficacy belief system is not a global trait but a differentiated set of self-beliefs linked to distinct realms of functioning"* (Bandura, 1997) . Multidomain measures reveal the patterning and degree of generality of people’s sense of personal efficacy.

(I wish to have helped you)

**REFERENCES**

- Bandura (1997), *Self-efficacy. The excercise of control*, New York: Freeman
- The article: *Guide for constructing self-efficacy scales* : link: http://web.stanford.edu/dept/psychology/bandura/pajares/014-BanduraGuide2006.pdf

Comment: self-efficacy is new to me and interesting. Thank you for sharing these resources. Unfortunately, although this is very useful to know, I find it to be more of a personality factor, such as Neuroticism. I am looking for the axioms of one's reasoning; what thing motivates a person to do something. I believe this is an intersection of philosophy and psychology. I hope to find works from others who attempt to define a basis of axioms to generally model one's philosophy or reasoning. I do not know correct terminology, and cannot find anything on the roots of one's motivation to do an action.

Answer (score 1):

I think what we call ideologies may be too varied across time and locations to capture in a questionnaire format. If you go one level more specific, to something like support of religion, free market, or moral situations, these may be more reliably and universally measurable.

One feature that feels universal is what constitutes a moral violation. Schwartz, Haidt, and others have worked in this area. One proposal is Moral Foundations Theory (MFT) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_foundations_theory. I've published in this area and I think it's a valuable perspective. Here's one place you can take the test: https://www.idrlabs.com/morality/6/test.php

However, MFT has been criticized recently for not being sufficiently coherent or reliable, eg. https://behavioralscientist.org/whats-wrong-with-moral-foundations-theory-and-how-to-get-moral-psychology-right/ discussion at https://twitter.com/Oliver_S_Curry/status/1110876328507645952